# Please update your Node runtime to version >=0.12.x

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Hi i'm working with ionic to build hybrid html app.

Every command i'm running i get the following warning:

```
******************************************************
 Upgrade warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly suggested to upgrade the following:

 Please update your Node runtime to version  >=0.12.x

******************************************************
```

If you can please advise how should i update the node runtime version

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is just asking to upgrade your `Node`. I normally use `nvm` with command `nvm install <version> && nvm use <version>` or you can use node helper as follows:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable // for stable version
sudo n 0.12.7 // for specific version like v0.12.7

// check the node version after install
node -v
```

Answer (score 2):

To install Node.js v5.x on either Ubuntu or Debian:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have installed `node.js` to your computer. You can either go to https://nodejs.org/ and get the updated version, or you can use `Node Version Manager (NVM)` which allows you to control multiple node versions at once.

I would recommend using NVM, as this avoids having to install nodejs with sudo, which can lead to other problems down the line.

Answer (score 1):

I use command:

```
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

and it works for me.